# Data attributes not working on dynamically added li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div `<div id="MetricsParentModelList"></div>` . In this div i am dynamically adding a ul element

```
$("#MetricsParentModelList").append('<ul class="modal__list mCustomScrollbar" id="MetricsParentModelListUl"></ul>');
```

After this i loop over a JSON object and add li elements dynamically to this ul element

```
for (var i = 0; i < metricsParentModel.length; i++) {
    var obj = metricsParentModel[i];
    $("#MetricsParentModelListUl").append('<li data-parentid=' + obj.ModelTypeYearID + ' data-name=' + obj.ModelTypeName + ' data-value=' + obj.ModelTypeID + ' data-id=' + obj.ModelTypeID + ' class="mModel"><a href="#"> ' + obj.ModelTypeName + '</a></li>');
}
```

Problem is that "data-parentid", "data-name", "data-value", "data-id" of li tag are not working. These do work correctly when i statically add the li element. How can i make it work dynamically.

Comment: May be you have to wrap "" around the custom attributes value like : $("#MetricsParentModelListUl").append('<li data-parentid="' + obj.ModelTypeYearID + '"<a href="#"> Test</a></li>');

Comment: its not working @Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

You need to have quotes around the data attributes. In the following I m adding " around each data-attribute.

Note - are you putting the object into an aray to iterate over. I just created a mocked up version of your code with the suggestion I made and some dummy data and it works as expected.

```js
var metricsParentModel = [{
'ModelTypeYearID': '1992',
'ModelTypeName':  'Charger',
'ModelTypeID': '1'
}, {
'ModelTypeYearID': '1998',
'ModelTypeName':  'Ranger',
'ModelTypeID': '2'
}]

$("#MetricsParentModelList").append('<ul class="modal__list mCustomScrollbar" id="MetricsParentModelListUl"></ul>');


for (var i = 0; i < metricsParentModel.length; i++) {
    var obj = metricsParentModel[i];
    $("#MetricsParentModelListUl").append('<li data-parentid=' + obj.ModelTypeYearID + ' data-name=' + obj.ModelTypeName + ' data-value=' + obj.ModelTypeID + ' data-id=' + obj.ModelTypeID + ' class="mModel"><a href="#"> ' + obj.ModelTypeName + '</a></li>');
    
console.log(obj.ModelTypeYearID + ' / ' + obj.ModelTypeName + ' / ' + obj.ModelTypeID + ' / ' + obj.ModelTypeID );
 //gives 1992 / Charger / 1 / 1 and 1998 / Ranger / 2 / 2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MetricsParentModelList"></div>
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code,  but it didn't work @gavgrif

Comment: I am reading the data from a Model. Here is the code
var metricsParentModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MetricsParentModel));
Do i need to convert it to array ?

Comment: I did it with your solution, but now the issue is that class "mModel" added in the li element is not working. @gavgrif